# Parse.com relationships and acl

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a "place" class and a "checkin" class, as well as the special "User" class. The "checkin" has a pointer to "place" and to "user". Simply speaking, a user can log he has visited a place.

The "place" class as only read permissions, and "checkin" has both read and write.

When creating a "checkin" object, I get the error 103: This user is not allowed to perform the update operation on place.

I tried with relationships instead of pointers and still got the same problem.

I do not want the "place" object to be updatable, and I do not understand why parse is internally trying to update it.

Any idea of why is this happening and how could I model the data to get it to work as I expect?

Edit: I add the code that makes the call to create the checkin object. As can be seen, place and user already exist so it is not my intent to update it.

```
let checkin = PFObject(className: "checkin")
    checkin["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    let place = PFObject(className: "place")
    place.objectId = shop.id
    checkin["place"] = place
    checkin.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (saved: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if saved && error == nil {
            success()
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if there is an internal link for indexing or something, you can certainly do it in cloud code as you can use the master key

Comment: I'm not sure but could it be because of this line? place.objectId = shop.id

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to diagnose without you sharing any code, as the problem might be related to what you are trying to do in code as well. I cannot comment for clarification so I'll post the answer to what I suspect is happening. If this is not the case, please comment or edit your post and I would be happy to try to help further.

The problem is probably not related to you using pointers... I use pointers and do not have issues like this.

What I think is happening is that based on your permissions, it is not letting the cloud to create the proper place. This is definitely true if you have also unchecked the ability to "create" a place. I understand the error suggests it is specifically an update, but I have had incorrect/misleading errors before as well. If this is the case, allow create. Or if you don't want the public to be able to create places, then make sure the current user has the proper ACL to do so or that the cloud code being run is using the master key.

If none of this is what is happening in your case, and you don't want to share code, I can recommend another workaround. Leave the overall class permissions for public for place to ensure that the initialization is performed correctly. Then, probably in a callback after saving, set the ACL to no write.

**Edit:** comments below address the added code

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the code in case it helps. As you can see, place already exists so there is no need to create or update it, it is set as a parameter to the checkin object.

Comment: @Jonatin I'm unfamiliar with some of your syntax, and I'm also unsure if "let" is supported by Parse, but these are probably not related to your problem.

However, you are creating a place object in your code when you have
`let place = PFObject(className: "place")`
Also you would need to save this object in order for it to be used by the parent checkin object later.

Comment: @Jonatin I thought about your code a little more. Are you trying to assign `checkin["place"]` to an existing `place` object that already has the id of `shop.id`?
For this you would need to perform a query. You can't simply set the id like that, you need to retrieve the actual object you are trying to reference. Also ignore my comment about syntax and let... I wasn't paying attention to your environment.

Comment: @papergozilla, I agree, I think he meant to query his place class for the object who's id matches shop.id.

Comment: @papergozilla It seems to work if i use the parse object instead of the id as you said. That way it works as expected. It would be nice if you could work with ids in order to reduce the number of requests though.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to query for the object with `shop.id`. I'm not very familiar with iOS programming, but the query on iOS would look like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ" block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {
    // Do something with the returned PFObject in the gameScore variable.
    NSLog(@"%@", gameScore);
}];
// The InBackground methods are asynchronous, so any code after this will run
// immediately.  Any code that depends on the query result should be moved
// inside the completion block above.
```

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide